# How to use resizebox without changing the font size?

Tags: boxes

I tried resizebox command at textwidth (0.5) but then I noticed the fonts being shrunk. Is it possible to resize box without affecting the font size? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just [`\parbox{<width>}{<text>}`](https://latexref.xyz/_005cparbox.html)?

Comment: you should clarify your question with an example of what you want do do. currently it is like asking for how to use `\color` without changing the color. hard to say anything other than do not use the command.

Comment: You can have a look here https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ to see what question format is expected on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of the writing environment.

1. text environment
2. *parbox* environment

1 :

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
text to be inserted
\end{minipage}
```

2 :

```
\parbox[c]{0.5\textwidth}{text to be inserted}
```

If it doesn't work properly you can try to use `\normalsize` command or environment.

1 :

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{normalsize}
text to be inserted
\end{normalsize}
\end{minipage}
```

or

```
\normalsize{
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
text to be inserted 
\end{minipage}
}
```

2 :

```
\parbox[c]{0.5\textwidth}{
\begin{normalsize}
text to be inserted
\end{normalsize}
}
```

or

```
\parbox[c]{0.5\textwidth}{\normalsize{text to be inserted}}
```

Be careful, the order of commands can be important in minipage environment. For example, if the `minipage` environment is included in `center` environment, the minipage is centered but not the text inside.

Comment: Thank you. All the alternative examples you provided work great and the boxes can be easily aligned left, right or center by adding raggedleft raggedright commands. Thank you again. The alignment is perfect when adding \usepackage{showframe}.

Comment: `\normalsize` does not take an argument. `\normalsize{ \begin{minipage}` applies `\normalsize` to the rest of the doument, and forces a space token to the left of the minipage. Neither of which are intended here.